# Dynamics CRM 2013 Merged Case

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on MS Dynamics CRM 2013 version

I tried to merged "Case B" into "Case A", and I add a "MERGED CASES" view in the "CASE" form,

When I am accessing "Case A", "Case B" shows in the "MERGED CASES" view of "Case A"

But when I access "Case B", is there any way to let user find out "Case A"?

I would like to create a view to do that, but I don't know which filter criteria is suitable for lookup the master case (Case A).

Thank you very much!!!

merge case steps : 
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2014/06/04/case-enhancements-in-dynamics-crm-2013-leo-release.aspx

It shows how to find the merged case, but not vice versa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am using a work around method,

I find that in the "Posts" Section on the Case form, there will be posts about merging action, there i can access the merge into case (Case A in our example)